# How to increase the performance of this 3 minute reporting query

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

We have a table `MyTable` with about 10.000.000 records which contains a record of all transactions processed in our application. This table has the user `Owner` who did the transaction, the date `ActionDate` on when it took place, the status `Status` and the order type `OrderType` of what type of transaction has been performed.

To generate a report where for every user the amount of transactions it did for every order type is displayed we have the following query as part of a stored procedure:

```
SELECT mt.Owner AS User,

(SELECT COUNT(ID) 
FROM `MyTable` mt
WHERE DATEDIFF(day, ActionDate, GETDATE()) = 0
AND mt.Owner = ca.Owner
AND mt.OrderType = 1
AND mt.Status <> 3
AND mt.Status <> 2  ) AS FIRST,

(SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM MyTable mt
WHERE DATEDIFF(day, ActionDate, GETDATE()) = 0
AND mt.Owner = mt.Owner
AND mt.OrderType = 2
AND mt.Status <> 3
AND mt.Status <> 2 ) AS SECOND,

(... Do this for six order types where mt.OrderType and the AS name changes ...)


(SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM MyTable mt
WHERE DATEDIFF(day, ActionDate, GETDATE()) = 0
AND mt.Owner =  mt.Owner
AND mt.Status<> 3
AND mt.Status<> 2 )
AS TOTAL

FROM MyTable mt
WHERE mt.Owner IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY mt.Owner
```

Some relevant information on indexes:

There are three indexes on `MyTable`. One on `ActionDate, Status, OrderType`, one on `Id`, and one on `Owner`.

These are created as follows:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX AnExampleOfAnIndex ON dbo.MyTable (ActionDate ASC, 
                                                             Status ASC, OrderType ASC)
WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, 
      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) 
ON [PRIMARY]
```

The query takes three minutes. Does someone see how it can be improved? Thanks.

Comment: What indexes are on the table?

Comment: @JohnM Great question I just thought it might be very relevant. Let me add them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of 7 Subqueries, you can just use one query. This should be a large performance gain:

```
SELECT owner [User],
       SUM(CASE WHEN OrderType = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [First],
       SUM(CASE WHEN OrderType = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [Second],
...
       COUNT('x') [Total]
FROM MyTable mt
WHERE status NOT IN (2,3)
  AND ActionDate >= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) 
  AND ActionDate < CAST(DATEADD(DAY, 1, GETDATE()) AS DATE)
GROUP BY owner
```

You'll also want to make sure that `DATEDIFF(day, ActionDate, GETDATE()) = 0` is doing what you want. What you're actually getting is anything that happened on the day that the date is run- the period between the start of the current day and the current time. If you're looking for anything else, say, transactions that took place YESTERDAY, i.e. before midnight this morning and after midnight the previous morning, you'd want to use different logic.

In order to get all users and the related records for them, whether or not there are any related records in the timeframe, you'd have to use a subquery failing another source for the users:

```
   SELECT  user_lst.owner [User],
           SUM(CASE WHEN mt.OrderType = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [First],
           SUM(CASE WHEN mt.OrderType = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [Second],
    ...
           COUNT(mt.owner) [Total]
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT owner FROM MyTable) user_lst
    LEFT JOIN MyTable mt
      ON mt.owner = user_lst.owner
      AND mt.status NOT IN (2,3)
      AND mt.ActionDate >= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) 
      AND mt.ActionDate < CAST(DATEADD(DAY, 1, GETDATE()) AS DATE)
    GROUP BY user_lst.owner
```

Also note that we had to change the aggregate logic for `[Total]`, as otherwise `COUNT('x')` would return 1 as `[Total]` for users with no activity in the timeframe.

Comment: Hmm it is a lot faster (6 times, as expected by your logic!), but it does not show the employees which have 0 for every work type. Do you see a way to get these as well?

Comment: apologies - work type? is that OrderType in MyTable?

Comment: Yes sorry. The original queries somehow gets all users first (it uses another scan on MyTable), and then adds the amounts for each `OrderType`. The new query only gets the users that have a total with at least 1. Don't know why.

Comment: Ah- I see. I'll edit my response to include that requirement.

Comment: The `DATEDIFF(day, mt.ActionDate, GETDATE()) = 0` can be improved to `mt.ActionDate >= CAST(GETDATE() AS date) AND mt.ActionDate < DATEADD(day, 1, CAST(GETDATE() AS date))`

Comment: And the `SUM(CASE WHEN mt.owner IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)` can be simplified to `COUNT(mt.owner)`

Comment: Agreed- the date logic is not optimal, but I think the improvement you've given there changes the behavior of the report.  @user2609980 - Is the required logic for date correct- are you looking for activity that happened in the last 24 hours from the time of the report run?

Comment: Incorporated `COUNT(mt.owner)`, `COUNT` is slightly less expensive than `SUM` and it's cleaner. +1. Thanks!

Comment: @ThomasCleberg I believe we are trying to get the results of the current day (so from 00:00 onwards). The problem is it still only returns the `Owners` that have at least 1 in total. This problem comes from the first part of the query, the SELECT with the SUMS seems to ignore results with 0 total.

Comment: @user2609980 - edited one more time to put the criteria in the join logic.

Comment: @ThomasCleberg. Thanks a lot. This was indeed the issue. The query performance went from 3 minutes to 3 seconds..! :-)

Comment: Wonderful to hear :)